# GetX,GetY method in Java

Tags: java, methods, public

Im trying to find the X and the Y when I have the radius and the alpha and I cant add any other but radius and alpha.

```
public Point (double x , double y) 
{
    _radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow (y, 2));
    _alpha = Math.atan(y/x) * 180 / Math.PI  ;
```

How I can find the X and the Y , I want to do the GetX , GetY methods

```
public double GetX()
{

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Err, x and y are passed to the constructor. Save them in fields, and return them from getX() and getY()? Note that Java methods conventionally start with a lower-case letter. And fields don't start with an underscore.

Comment: That's what they want from us to do in the university, they said us we cant add any other fields but _radius and _alpha

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add fields for `x` and `y` and save the values in the constructor. Like,

```
private double x, y;
public Point (double x , double y) 
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    _radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow (y, 2));
    _alpha = Math.atan(y/x) * 180 / Math.PI  ;
```

Then you can `return x;` and `return y;` in your `getter` methods.

Comment: Elliot , I forgot to add it but im not allowed to use any other fields but _radius and _alpha.

Comment: @Daniel Oh. Then you can't get x or y.